# Angular2 RC and dynamic routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

We have a SPA app written in Angular which takes advantage of loading routes dynamically (as opposed to statically defined routes).

Over time, the number of these dynamically loaded UI components will grow and grow. For any given customer deployment, we will only be using a small subset of the possible components.  At runtime, the list of components will be data driven.  So my desire is to take that list of components and do the following:
-   define an application route for each component at runtime
-   lazy load that component

It’s a problem that has been solved in the Angular 1 version of our application (using ocLazyLoad package and angular’s $stateProvider)

It appears to be solvable in some of the later Beta releases of Angular2 (using AsyncRoutes and the router.config method - see technique [here](http://blog.mgechev.com/2015/09/30/lazy-loading-components-routes-services-router-angular-2/))

But in RC1 that AsyncRoutes and router.config method seems to be broken.

I can find very little with respect to guidance for loading components/routes asynchronously in the Angular2 release candidates.

Is there a canonical example for doing this with the latest candidates?

Comment: Angular2 indeed uses lazy routes. In angular-cli they are the default when creating a route with the scaffolding function. It generates a component in  folder with a + prefix. There is  great talk from Mishko at ngconf 2016 https://youtu.be/d8yAdeshpcw

Comment: Yes, we've seen that video.  We can't quite get it to work as advertised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new router (`>= RC.3`) https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-interface.html#!#resetConfig-anchor `resetConfig` can be used

> ```
> router.resetConfig([
>  { path: 'team/:id', component: TeamCmp, children: [
>    { path: 'simple', component: SimpleCmp },
>    { path: 'user/:name', component: UserCmp }
>  ] }
> ]);
> ```

Lazy loading components is now (RC.5) implemented using lazy modules.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11437#issuecomment-245995186 provides an **RC.6** Plunker

Comment: I've seen the router.resetConfig given as an answer to several variations of this question, but have never seen a working example. When I've tried to use it I've had strange behaviour with components being instantiated multiple times. Do you by any chance have a link to a plunker where this is used?

Comment: Sorry, no. I haven't tried it myself. I have yet to dive into routing with modules myself.

Comment: Günter is correct, full lazy loading is in RC5.  Be aware, some angular-related bootstrap components are slightly behind and only jibe with this functionality in their nightly builds

Answer (score 0):

With RC5 ng2 team finally found a way to dynamically load router
1. AppModule is introduced and every is modulised ( back to AngularJS 1 date!)
2. "loadChildren" let you can load from files from disk:

```
{path: screenId, loadChildren: 'app/screens/' + screenId + '.module' })
```

Here is my sample code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/nm5m7N?p=preview

Comment: did you forgot some thing ? plnkr is broken ?

Comment: This is an example of lazy loading, not dynamic loading. You are just lazyloading the module according to your screenId, which in your plunker you have hardcoded earlier in the function. The question is how can you do this when you first have to asynchronously fetch the routes from a file or database?

Comment: ng2 rc5 router is asynchronous by nature , and.  app/screens/page1.module.ts  is a file in my disk,  same as page2.module.ts and page3....

Comment: Have a close look MyRouterLink.ts in my example,  it is dynamic loaded component

Comment: @LongField your plunker is helpful, could you please demonstrate how do i load routes that would be coming from a Http call , or lets say a component's method. My Use case is that after dashboard is loaded i want to dynamically lazy load the routes.

Comment: Have a close look MyRouterLink.ts, routes are coming from http call, and pages are lazy loaded