# How can I dynamically position the <router-outlet> depending on the url called?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a complex interface where I have a list of dynamic items (imagine an accordion widget) in a page (here **about page**) and when I call this url :

```
/about/item/1
```

it "routes" to one of the accordion item and loads the content in the clicked list item (one item of the accordion).

Specifically, what I want to do is this :

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-about',
    template: `
      <ul>
          // dynamic list
          <li>
              <a [routerLink]="['/about/item', 1]">Item 1</a>
              // <router-outlet></router-outlet>
              // if url is /about/item/1
          </li>
          <li>
              <a [routerLink]="['/about/item', 2]">Item 2</a>
              // <router-outlet></router-outlet>
              // if url is /about/item/2
          </li>
      </ul>         
    `
})
export class AboutComponent { }
```

I'm using **angular : 2.0.0-rc.4**, **angular/router: 3.0.0-beta.2**

It doesn't seem to be the right practice. How can I do that the "angular way" ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Apparently it's a RC5 issue where you cannot dynamically place a router-outlet in view because of a race condition as explained here. Hope my case will be resolve in the next router release. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9500

Answer (score 1):

You could give the router-outlets names and define the name on the route which outlet the component should be added to

```
<router-outlet name="a"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="b"></router-outlet>
```

```
{ path: 'a', component: A, outlet: 'a'}
{ path: 'b', component: B, outlet: 'b'}
```

See also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterConfig-type-alias.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: I have a dynamic list of items ... can I set dynamic routes ? in my about page's component ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37623306/angular2-rc-and-dynamic-routes/38095784#38095784. You might also be able to use route parameters (don't know your detailed requirements) where a part of the path is variable to not need a new route for each value. You'll need a route for each component though except you add the component imperatively depending on the route parameter inside the routed component.

Comment: I want the exact same router outlet ( I dont want to refine the route ). It's more a matter of where the <router-outlet> is placed in the page than it's definition itself

Comment: I don't know a way to move router-outlets around.